# Can't connect to PostgreSQL database on LAN from separate machine

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin

This should be fairly simple, I've done it before, but I am stumped. I have a PostgreSQL server set up on one machine on my internet and I am trying to access it from a different machine on the same network. I can connect to the database when on the same machine using localhost but not from other machines using that machines IP. The server is `10.0.0.23` and the other computers are of the same format (`10.0.0.21` etc).

I enter `jdbc:postgresql://10.0.0.23:5432/dbname` and the `user/pass`, but it says "The connection attempt failed". The `postgresql.conf` file has been edited to uncomment the line that allows it to listen for all addresses (and configs refreshed in PgAdmin). I don't think that `pg_hba.conf` needs to be edited because I am on the same network, but that could be wrong. I have also tried editing the `pg_hba.conf` though to include the `10.0.0.X` IPs but that did not help.

I'm fairly lost at this point, so any thoughts appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to reload the configuration after editing the `pg_hba.conf`, and please paste the error from PostgreSQL logs

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who this might help, I ended up figuring out that it was a firewall issue. I don't remember having to do this before but I went into the Windows defender firewall and created a rule for port 5432 and I can connect now.